# select and compare x or y from a svg rect in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, svg

How can i select and compare x or y element value from a svg rect in jquery?

svg looks like this:

```
<svg id="demo" width="100%" height="40" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <rect id="stretchy" x="20" y="40" width="100%" height="40" fill="#b7b7b7" stroke-width="5"></rect>
        <text x="50%" y="50%" font-family="Verdana" font-size="20" text-anchor="middle" dy=".3em"> text </text>
    </svg>
```

I wanna use it in something like this:

```
if($('#stretchy').css('x')!='20'){
code
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the answear to this question:

if($('rect[id="stretchy"]').attr('x')!='20'){
code
}

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,
To get value of **X** and **Y** of rect having **id** `stretchy`

```
var retX = $('#stretchy').attr('x');
var retY = $('#stretchy').attr('y');
```

```js
var retX = $('#stretchy').attr('x');
var retY = $('#stretchy').attr('y');
if( retX == '20'){
   console.log("X = 20");
}
if( retY == '40'){
   console.log("Y = 40");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="demo" width="100%" height="40" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect id="stretchy" x="20" y="40" width="100%" height="40" fill="#b7b7b7" stroke-width="5" stroke="#00cc00"></rect>
    <text x="50%" y="50%" font-family="Verdana" font-size="20" text-anchor="middle" dy=".3em"> text </text>
</svg>
```